# How to solve lsass.exe very high ram usage?

Tags: windows-7, memory-usage

My machine has been feeling sluggish and I'm noticing that the `lsass.exe` process is allocating nearly 2GB, which seems unusually high.

here:
[image]

(Win7x64,Vertex2,Gtx460,i7-2600,8gb ram)

Any ideas?

Comment: `lsass.exe` is the service responsible for managing authentication. Do you have anything unusual about your authentication? (Work environment, multiple users logging onto the system, remote desktop, etc.)?

Comment: Do you see any "unusual" events being logged in any of the Windows event logs?

Comment: Well i dont have a domain or something in here (nor AD), its a standalone workstation. maybe because i have RSAT?. iv noticed that the lsass looks like CNG Key Isolation service (or KeyIso), when i try to stop the service i cant cause it have dependencies like wlan and eap. here: http://i.imgur.com/2Y7t9.jpg

Comment: and il check the event log now

Comment: hey iv just seen the the event log have unusual number of "The following fatal alert was received: 42." evnets (id 36887 and source Schannel)

Comment: I would be more worried about the fact Firefox is using nearly 2GB of memory.

Comment: more then lsass? ff is a big problem i should report in another post iv a lot of things to say about the ongoing memory leaks of firefox

Comment: @Ramhound 2GB of memory is about par for any browser I use these days, save for Lynx. Today's web is very memory intensive unless you browse with just 2 tabs or so.

Answer (score 3):

On my system, `lsass.exe` is consuming about 10K.

I'm at work.  On our company's main domain controller, `lsass.exe` is up to about 80K.

Either your `lsass.exe` is infected, a piece of malware is trying to do something funny, or (least likely) something over the network is trying to do the same.

It's also possible you may have a legitimate program making a legitimate amount of authentication requests - possibly something running as another user accessing many, many files in a short period of time or similar.

Comment: can that be RSAT tools? cause ive scan with alot of scanner for a virus or malware an i cant see something that can cause this

Comment: @energydream2007 - Disable the tools and report back.  You need to avoid terms like `RSAT` when you don't explain what it means.

Comment: Yes as of now uninstall the RSAT resolve the prob - the usage is now 30k~. and everybody know what is RSAT...

Comment: @energydream2007 Err, no we don't. Googling the term brings up a bunch of different products as well.

Comment: if you assisting ppl in the IT world you suppose to know this specific tool

Comment: [UPDATE]: as of know after alot of hours of removing the rsat tool and using the machine - the current usage is 160MB for lsass.exe, i think it still little high right?