# lsass.exe causes memory leak

Tags: windows-7

2 weeks back I noticed high utilization of memory even though I was just running a browser. After a bit digging in, I found out that the process lsass.exe (used by service- CNG Key Isolation service) is chewing up the memory. It starts off with 72k of memory utilization and over a period of time keeps growing with the Memory it utilizes..noticed it using 6 GB and rebooted the system... I would have kept going if not reboot.

I scanned it (in both normal and Safe mode) using ESET AV and it does not report any problem of any Virus/spyware etc..

Even went through the following link:
[How to solve lsass.exe very high ram usage?](https://superuser.com/questions/477501/how-to-solve-lsass-exe-very-high-ram-usage)

The issue here was with his RSAT tool, which he uninstalled and the issue got resolved... I want to know how to find out which application or tool is causing the hight utilization of "lsass.exe" process? What is the best why to dig in further?

I dont think it is a virus. It has more do with a application trying to Authenticate or something..

Any help in this regard would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone please help me? Otherwise I will have to factory reset my M4600

Comment: Use the [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) tool, and check the "LSA Providers" tab.  Those DLLs get loaded into the LSASS process, and any non-Microsoft entries would be good suspects.